# tastypie: save_m2m

Tags: tastypie

My understanding of why save_m2m is needed in a tastypie resource is not yet clear. In a POST, if I post data only pertinent to the creation of one model and do not send anything related to the m2m object, do I still need to do a save_m2m. Why is it needed? What happens if I override save_m2m to do nothing? It seems to work fine and my resource is created, I'm not sure of any hidden implications that this might lead to. Could you please comment.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have any fields marked `is_m2m=True` the method won't actually do anythig. From tastypie docstrings in save_m2m:

```
"""
Handles the saving of related M2M data.

Due to the way Django works, the M2M data must be handled after the
main instance, which is why this isn't a part of the main ``save`` bits.

Currently slightly inefficient in that it will clear out the whole
relation and recreate the related data as needed.
"""
```

Inside the tastypie's resources `save_m2m` method checks for fields with is_m2m set to True if  none is found it just doesn't do anything, so if your resource class doesn't have any m2m and any other resources won't inherit from it you can override the `save_m2m` method to do nothing.

You will be actually one loop ahead of tastypie (a tiny speedup woohoo! ;)).